# What is the most efficient way to map/transform/cast a Cassandra BoundStatement's ResultSet to a Java classe built using the Object-mapping API?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Is there a builtin way in DataStax Java for Apache Cassandra to map the ResultSet coming from a BoundStatement to the domain objects Java classes built with using the Object-mapping API?

I am a newbie moving from the Mapper + Accessor approach to BoundStatement approach and would like to continue using the domain objects' Java classes built with the Object-mapping API so I do minimal changes to the implementation of my DAO methods while moving to the BoundStatement. I am looking to do it in a generic way and avoid to iterate over each ResultSet row and do a row.get one by one for each domain object.

While using the Mapper + Accessor approach, the Result.all() do that very well. Could not find anything similar to the BoundStatement approach.

Thanks

IPVP

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can accomplish mapping a `ResultSet` to a `com.datastax.driver.mapping.Result` by instantiating a `Mapper` for your object, and then using [`Mapper.map`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/mapping/Mapper.html#map-com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet-).  Here is an example, taken from the [java driver's tests](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1.9/driver-mapping/src/test/java/com/datastax/driver/mapping/MapperTest.java#L405-L416) that takes a `ResultSet` from a regularly executed query and maps it to a `Result<Post>`, and then iterates over the Result to access each mapped Post:

```
MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(session);

Mapper<Post> m = manager.mapper(Post.class);
...
// Retrieve posts with a projection query that only retrieves some of the fields
ResultSet rs = session.execute("select user_id, post_id, title from posts where user_id = " + u1.getUserId());

Result<Post> result = m.map(rs);
for (Post post : result) {
    assertThat(post.getUserId()).isEqualTo(u1.getUserId());
    assertThat(post.getPostId()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(post.getTitle()).isNotNull();

    assertThat(post.getDevice()).isNull();
    assertThat(post.getTags()).isNull();
}
```

Comment: I am using datastax cassadra java driver 3.0.2, but It doesn't have MappingManager class. Is your above example applicable with driver version 3.x as well ?

Comment: The mapper is provided by the cassandra-driver-mapping module (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-mapping)

Answer (score 3):

Starting from version 4.1.0 of the DataStax Java Driver, there is a different way to map objects using the [new object mapper](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.4/upgrade_guide/#4-1-0).

The code from Andy Tolbert's answer would be something like the code below.

First, we need to enable the annotation processor. Using Maven, add the following to `pom.xml`:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
                        <artifactId>java-driver-mapper-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>4.4.0</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Let's assume there is a keyspace called `posts`, with a single table `posts` that has columns `user_id`, `post_id` and `title`.

We need to create a class called `Post` (which we'll map to table name `posts` using `@CqlName` annotation) as below.

```java
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.CqlName;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Entity;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.PartitionKey;

@Entity
@CqlName("posts")
public class Post {

    @PartitionKey
    private String postId;
    private String title;
    private String userId;

    // add getters/setters/no-args constructor/equals/hashCode
}
```

Now we create an interface called `PostDao`, which has the queries we want to execute.

```java
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Dao;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Select;

@Dao
public interface PostDao {

    @Select
    Post findById(String postId);
}
```

Finally, we create an interface for the mapper.

```java
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlIdentifier;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.DaoFactory;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.DaoKeyspace;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Mapper;

@Mapper
public interface PostMapper {

    @DaoFactory
    PostDao postDao(@DaoKeyspace CqlIdentifier keyspace);
}
```

When we run `mvn compile`, the annotation processor will generate a class called `PostMapperBuilder` (which we'll need for running the queries).

```java
CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder().build();

PostMapper postMapper = new PostMapperBuilder(session).build();

PostDao dao = postMapper.postDao(CqlIdentifier.fromCql("posts"));

Post post = dao.findById("a1b2c3d4"); // or whatever the postId is...
```

Be sure to check out the documentation on [configuring the annotation processor](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.4/manual/mapper/config/) and on [creating entities](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.4/manual/mapper/entities/).