# Best way to convert Cassandra ResultSet to java objects in OSS driver

Tags: java, cassandra, driver, datastax-java-driver

We are in the process of migrating from Cassandra DSE to OSS driver and the pain point is converting the result set into a list of Java objects. I don't want to use Mapper annotation, like detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701817/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-map-transform-cast-a-cassandra-boundstatement)

So what is the most efficient way to convert ResultSet into list of java objects? Any suggestion highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use Mapper then just need to write converting function that will take Row, extract all necessary columns, and return POJO constructed from teh extracted data... I don't see other ways, except writing an adhoc version of object mapper that would use the reflection to match POJO's field names with the column names